# Folder write permission on a symlink (Linux/CentOS)

Tags: directory, centos, symlink, chown, ln

I am having issues with writing to the target folder of a symlink. The files can be read without any issues, but as soon as I try to upload something to the target folder I get a write permission error.

```
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 user1 user1   47 Mar 17 12:35 data -> /home/user2/public_html/apps/public/data/
```

The target folder has 0777 permissions and is owned by user2

```
drwxrwsrwx. 135 user2 user2 12288 Mar 16 10:18 .
```

What am I missing, why can't I write files/folders to the symlink target? I am running WHM/Cpanel on CentOS if that makes any difference. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Most linux systems require a user's home directory to have 700 perms.
user1 can't access user2's home directory or anything below it.

You should move these directories somewhere other than a user's home dir if you want multiple users to have access...i.e. /opt/ or /var/